# What happened with Kamisama Dolls?

Tags: kamisama-dolls

I watched the entire anime, but they leave the ending open. There's no further continuation in the manga of what we watched in the anime. They were going to make a movie, but they never did. What happened to the show and the manga? Is there some continuation in some novel?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to know what happened to the show, or what happened to the characters?

Comment: @kuwaly Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 1):

The manga has ended and the anime has ended as well. There's nothing left presumably to animate or write about, so that's the finish of that.

Actually, [searches for a movie bring up nothing](https://www.google.ca/search?q=kamisama%20dolls%20movie). So, are you sure that wasn't a false memory?

Comment: It is probably misunderstanding due to the ending: "The story of how Kyouhei becomes awesome is left for another time"... or something along that line.